# IOS voice command start recording

Tags: ios, camera, recording

Currently I am developing an IOS app.I need once I open the camera through application then when i say "start recording" then recording should start automatically. Once i say "Cut" then it should stop. and ask for save video share etc.

My main concern is regarding voice command. recording should start stop through voice command.

Looking forward for experts suggestions.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Siri is not yet exposed to developers there are lot of third party sdks dat can be used for recognizing speech.

I have used 
http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/Introduction.html

There are number of other sdks too ,u can easily google them
U have to set the words dat u want to recognize  and perform intended action.

All d best with your app!!